# How to assign an error for each entry from a different column

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
 include ('database_connection.php');
include ('navigs.php');
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
$error = array();//Declare An Array to store any error message  
if (empty($_POST['firstname'])) {//if no name has been supplied 
    $error[] = 'Please enter your firstname ';//add to array "error"
} else {
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];//else assign it a variable
}

if (empty($_POST['nickname'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter your nickname';
} else {
     $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
}        

if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter your e-mail ';
} else {

    if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['email'])) {
       //regular expression for email validation
        $email = $_POST['email'];
    } else {
         $error[] = 'Your email address is invalid  ';
    }


}

 if (empty($_POST['altemail']))      {
 $error[] = 'Please enter your alternative email';
 } else {
if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['altemail'])) { 
$altemail = $_POST['altemail'];
} else {
 $error[] = 'Not a  valid email ';
}

}   
  if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error[] = 'Please enter a password ';
 } else {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
 }


  if (empty($error)) //send to Database if there's no error '

 { // If everything's OK...

    // Make sure the email address is available:
    $query_verify_email = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE Email ='$email' OR   Altemail='$altemail' OR nickname='$nickname'";
    $result_verify_email = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_verify_email);
    if (!$result_verify_email) {//if the Query Failed ,similar to  if($result_verify_email==false)
        echo ' Database Error ';
    }

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result_verify_email) == 0) { // IF no previous user is using this email .


        // Create a unique  activation code:
        $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));


        $query_insert_user = "INSERT INTO `users` ( `firstname`, `nickname`, `email`, `activation`, `altemail`, `password` ) VALUES ( '$firstname', '$nickname', '$email', '$activation', '$altemail', ENCRYPT('$password'))";


        $result_insert_user = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_insert_user);
        if (!$result_insert_user) {
            echo 'Erreur SQL ';
        }

        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { //If the Insert Query was successfull.


            // Send the email:
            $message = " Pour activer ton compte, click sur ce lien:\n\n";
            $message .= WEBSITE_URL . 'activate.php?email=' . urlencode($email) . "&key=$activation";
            mail($altemail, 'Registration Confirmation', $message, 'From: noreply@mysite.org');

            // Flush the buffered output.


            // Finish the page:
            echo '<div class="success">An email has been sent to the following addres:   '.$altemail.'   Please click on the link to activate your account </div>';


        } else { // If it did not run OK.
            echo '<div class="errormsgbox">An error has occurred please try again later .</div>';
        }

    } else { // The email address is not available.
 echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >Either the nickname is already taken, the email address is already taken, or the alternative email you supplied is already on our  system</div>';
    }

} else {//If the "error" array contains error msg , display them



  echo '<div class="errormsgbox"> <ol>';
    foreach ($error as $key => $values) {

        echo '  <li>'.$values.'</li>';



    }
    echo '</ol></div>';

}

 mysqli_close($dbc);//Close the DB Connection

} // End of the main Submit conditional.



 ?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
  <title>Create you email account</title>
  <style type="text/css">
 body {
 font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,     sans-serif;
 font-size:12px;
  }
  .registration_form {
margin:0 auto;
width:500px;
padding:14px;
 }
 label {
width: 10em;
float: left;
margin-right: 0.5em;
display: block
}
.submit {
 float:right;
 }
 fieldset {
background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
width: 500px;
 }
  legend {
color: #fff;
background: #80D3E2;
border: 1px solid #781351;
padding: 2px 6px
 }
 .elements {
padding:10px;
 }
 p {
border-bottom:2px solid #B7DDF2;
color:#666666;
font-size:13px;
margin-bottom:20px;
padding-bottom:9px;
 }
 a{
  color:#0099FF;
  font-weight:bold;
 }

 /* Box Style */


  .success, .warning, .errormsgbox, .validation {
border: 1px solid;
margin: 0 auto;
padding:10px 5px 10px 50px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 10px center;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:450px;

 }

 .success {

color: #4F8A10;
background-color: #DFF2BF;
background-image:url('images/success.png');
 }
  .warning {

color: #9F6000;
background-color: #FEEFB3;
background-image: url('images/warning.png');
 }
 .errormsgbox {

color: #D8000C;
background-color: #FFBABA;
background-image: url('images/error.png');

  }
  .validation {

color: #D63301;
background-color: #FFCCBA;
background-image: url('images/error.png');
   }



    </style>

   </head>
   <body>


 <form action="index.php" method="post" class="registration_form">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Créer Un Compte Mail </legend>

  <p>Create an email account <span style="background:#EAEAEA none repeat scroll 0 0;line-height:2;margin-left:220px;;padding:7px 7px;">Tu as un compe? <a href="http://www.mysite.net/webmail/">Login</a></span> </p>

<div class="elements">
  <label for="firstname">Firstname / Initiale  :</label>
  <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="elements">
  <label for="nickname">NickName  :</label>
  <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" size="25" />
</div>  
<div class="elements">
  <label for="email">E-mail  :</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="elements">
  <label for="altemail">Email de verification :</label>
  <input type="text" id="altemail" name="altemail" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="elements">
  <label for="password">Your Password  :</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" />
</div>
<div class="submit">
 <input type="hidden" name="formsubmitted" value="TRUE" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
Go Back to <a href="index.php">Account Verification on sign up</a>
</body>
```

Hi all What I am trying to achieve here is this:

When a user enters a username, an email address and an alternative email, to be able to check whether these entries do not already exist in the database and return an error accordingly.

For instance if the username is already taken it will warn the user to choose another usename and so on.
At the moment it only returns one error if any of the three entries is found, how can I do it in order to return an error according to the entry that is found in the table Please.

As an update, my question initially was to check two separate fields within the table,

First this form is to allow people to create their own email account, but for doing so, they also need to provide an existing email address in order to send them a link to activate their account.

I can check the three fields successfully but the problem I am having, is how to return an error for each of the fields separately.

At the moment I am only able to return the same error for any of the fields.

First it will check the validity of the email addresses

Second it will check if the email addresses both are not already on the system, the one the user is trying to create and the one he's providing as an alternative email address

Third it will check if the nickname is already taken.

Right now it does all of the above, the only problem I am having is how to get it to return an error for each one.

So the user won't get confused, and s/he would know which field to change in order to complete his / her registration.

If you could help me with just this

```
 } else { // The email address is not available.
 echo '<div class="errormsgbox" >Either the nickname is already taken, the email   address is already taken, or the alternative email you supplied is already on our     system</div>';
  }
```

Thank you all for your help it is much appreciated

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're going at it 1990s style by slamming together database access, HTML and CSS into a giant `.php` file rather than use a framework like [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/), [CodeIgnighter](http://codeignighter.com/) or [FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/)? Applications of this sort are extremely hard to improve and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Do some `print_r($error)` between the different calls. Or use xdebug in order to step through your code.

Anyway I would advise you about using a CMS or Framework to build upon and not mixing all up in one file.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a framework like `Kohana`, will make your life easier. This will also give you the ability to make sure only the specified fields are going through to the database, and sanitized. Don't want to deal with mass assignment (I'm bender from the future)

Create a set of rules for the available fields

```
$rules = array(
  'email' => array(
     'valid_email',
     'not_empty'
   ),
   'nickname' => array(
     'not_empty', 
   )
)
```

Write a method to check against the rules and the get the messages back or return it to true.

```
foreach ($_POST as $field)
{
   if (isset($rules[$field]))
   {
       // Check the rules
       foreach ($rules[$field] as $rule)
       { 
          $check = call_user_func(array(Valid, $rule), $field);
          if ( !$check->isValid )
          {
              $this->errors[] = $check->message;
           }
           else
           {
              // Insert or do whatever you need to with the data
           }
       }

   }

}
```